# How to clone multiple schemas/tables from one folder to multiple other folders using a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, clone, azure-databricks

I have several databases in Databricks, each containing several tables/schemas. I want to create a dictonary (path of source database: path of target database) to clone all the schemas/tables contained or iterate over them with Python if the tables already exist.

What am I doing wrong? I tried this, but its not working.

```
import shutil

files = {"abfss://<file_system>@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net": "abfss://<file_system2>@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net"} # create dictonary

for source, move in files.items():
    shutil.copyfile(source, f"dir/{move}")
```

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2297266253035384> in <module>
      1 for source, move in files.items():
----> 2     shutil.copyfile(source, f"dir/{move}")

/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    262         os.symlink(os.readlink(src), dst)
    263     else:
--> 264         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    265             # macOS
    266             if _HAS_FCOPYFILE:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abfss://...dfs.core.windows.net/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and got the below results.

First set the ADLS gen2 configurations with Access key to access the files.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "access key")
```

[image]

Next using `dbutils.fs.ls()`, get the list of paths from the filesystems (containers).
Then generate the result dictionary.

```
con1_list=dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://<filesystem1>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/")
path_list1=[]
for i in  range(0,len(con1_list)):
    path_list1.append(con1_list[i].path)   
print("first list : ",path_list1)

con2_list=dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://<filesystem2>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/")
path_list2=[]
for i in  range(0,len(con2_list)):
    path_list2.append(con2_list[i].path)   
print("second list : ",path_list2)

res_dict=dictionary = dict(zip(path_list1, path_list2))
print("Files dictionary : ",res_dict)
```

[image]

I have tried with `shutil` but not able to get the desired result. `shutil`not detecting `abfss` files might be the reason for it.  **As a workaround** you can do the same with `dbutils.fs.mv()`.

```
for source,move in res_dict.items():
    dbutils.fs.mv(source, move)
```

[image]

In the above `mv` will move the files from source to destination. If you want your source files to be there in source even after this, you can use `dbutils.fs.cp()` which will only copy the files to destination files.

```
for source,move in res_dict.items():
    dbutils.fs.cp(source, move)
```